# How []interface{} in Go is implemented?

Tags: go, memory

In Go I can do something like this:

```
func main() {
    var intSlice []interface{}
    intSlice = append(intSlice, "hello world")
    intSlice = append(intSlice, 1)
    for _, v := range intSlice {
        fmt.Println(v)   // hello world
                         // 1
    }
}
```

Since a slice is deep down an array, without given a specific type to that array, how can Go know the layout of this array's memory structure? If it's a []string then I know that for every iteration I have to add current address with 4 to get the next item's address, but for an interface{} how can Go knows what to do?  I am confused. One possible explain for this is that interface{} is actually a pointer, so []interface{} stores pointers only, the value 1 or "hello world" is stored somewhere outside of the slice. Am I right about this?

Comment: This isn't specific to slices, you'd have to solve the same "problem" with just an plain `interface{}` variable.

Comment: Sorry but it's the using of `[]interface{} `  makes me thinking about it.

Comment: "Since a slice is deep down an array, without given a specific type to that array, how can Go know the layout of this array's memory structure?" `interface{}` *is* a specific type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interface is two values: a pointer to the value, and a pointer to the type of the value. So a `[]interface{}` containing all `int` values is simply an array of interfaces, where each element containing those two values, with each element of the array pointing to the `int` value, and to its type.